# Dealing with transactions after crashes

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Currently I've been working in an accounting program which uses double entry system. When a record is made, an account is debited and the other is credited, so their amounts have to be updated in a database.

Let's say that just after the first account is updated in the database the system crashes and the amount of the second account does not change; this scenario would cause an inconsistency in the data so my question is: what is the best way to deal with this problem? Should I reverse the first transaction as soon as the database recovers or just keep trying to update the second account?

I'm using hibernate and spring framework with mysql. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352870/will-mysql-transactions-rollback-after-system-crash

Comment: Crashes can happen, and it might be messy, but keep in mind that if your Java application crashes, then transactions in MySQL should still be atomic, i.e. either the whole thing succeeded, or it didn't happen at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need distributed transactions and 2 phase commits here.

See [the example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example.html) for 2 DataSources (seem to be your case) and one more [example](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) for DataSource plus message queue